# Prove that product of two locally connected spaces is locally connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two locally connected spaces. I need to show that $Z = X \times Y$ is locally connected. Here is my attempt:

**Proof**. Let $z=(x, y)\in Z$ and $N$ be any neighborhood of $z$. I need to show that $\exists U\subset N, U$ is connected. Now, since $Z = X\times Y, N_x\times N_y\subset N$, where $N_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $N_y$ is a neighborhood of $Y$. Since $X$ is locally connected, $\exists U_x\subset N_x, U_x$ is connected. Similarly, $\exists U_y\subset N_y, U_y$ is connected. Now let $U=U_x\times U_y$.

I tried prove that $U$ must be connected by contradiction but to no avail. Maybe the correct approach would be to show that connectivity of $U$ follows from the fact that it is a product of connected sets but I am not sure how to make such a leap. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The product of two connected sets is connected, and likewise the product of two open sets is open. You can prove both of these statements pretty immediately from the definitions of connectness and openness. Thus $U$ is connected and open.

Comment: Yes, if I could prove that the product of two connected sets is connected, I would have no problems but this is exactly what I cannot show.

Comment: well, then ask that as a question (or just look it up; there are plenty of existing proofs)

Answer (score 0):

If U were not connected, there would be a set $F \subset U $ that was closed and open; then, the projection of that set down to either X or Y would also be clopen (because the projection is continuous); but X and Y are locally connected, which means that $\pi_X(F)=U_X, \pi_Y(F)=U_Y$ (or the empty set of course, but that alternative is analogous). Then, projecting back, you get that $F=U$; similarly for the case where either the projections were empty, $F=\emptyset$.

That is, you proved that the only clopen subset of $U$ is either $U$ itself or the empty set, ie $U$ is connected.

Comment: I do not think I understand how you got to the fact that $F=U$ when $\pi_X(F)=U_x$ and $\pi_Y(F)=U_y$.

Comment: Projecting back the first component, you get $F=U_x \times P$, for some $P\subset Y$. From the second component, you get $F=S \times U_y$, for some $S\subset X$. By comparing the two you conclude that $F=U_x \times U_y=U$